# What is Spark? How can it benefit me?

Tags: xmpp, openfire, smack

I was reading about the [Smack API](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/) and XMPP server [Openfire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/%E2%80%8E) . I also read about [Spark](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/spark/), an open source IM client.

I am still reading about each of them but one thing confuses me. Do I need Spark? I mean, what does it do? I could have my own chat interface.

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place?

Comment: @hexafraction want to make a simple chat application..like _google talk_ but with a web interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need Spark itself to create a chat application. Let's say you're making a web browser. While it may be nice to take inspiration from Chromium, it is not necessary, and is an independent product. The same happens here.

Spark is a client for the XMPP protocol, it seems. Making a chat application involves a server and a client. If you are using XMPP there are many clients and many servers out there so you only need to create a server, or a client, or both if you'd like.

Comment: okay..so `spark` and `openfire` together let you create your own chat system ? Is that so ?

Comment: @SuhailGupta Yes. They are a client and a server of the same protocol.